# How to Pass Multiple Parameters In URL String From Select2 Multi Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I have a select2 initialized on an input field which is using  multiple: true when I'm initializing select2 on this field. I have been trying to figure out how to take multiple options selected from this HTML input field and convert them to a string to pass them in the url as follows - url?employer=1&employer=2&employer=3

The problem I am experiencing is after I have used

```
jQuery.param(JSON.stringify(employerKey))
```

This encodes the params and when I decode it it is still nothing meaningful. Here's a sample of what console logs out.

```
0=%5B&1=%7B&2=%22&3=w&4=e&5=b&6=s&7=e&8=r&9=v&10=i&11=c&12=e&13=I&14=d&15=%22&16=%3A&17=%22&18=e&19=c&20=i&21=%22&22=%2C&23=%22&24=e&25=m&26=p&27=l&28=o&29=y&30=e&31=r&32=N&33=o&34=%22&35=%3A&36=1&37=8&38=7&39=%2C&40=%22&41=i&42=d&43=%22&44=%3A&45=1&46=8&47=7&48=%2C&49=%22&50=t&51=e&52=x&53=t&54=%22&55=%3A&56=%22&57=0&58=0&59=2&60=1&61=3&62=7&63=+&64=%7C&65=+&66=n&67=u&68=l&69=l&70=%22&71=%7D&72=%2C&73=%7B&74=%22&75=w&76=e&77=b&78=s&79=e&80=r&81=v&82=i&83=c&84=e&85=I&86=d&87=%22&88=%3A&89=%22&90=e&91=c&92=i&93=%22&94=%2C&95=%22&96=e&97=m&98=p&99=l&100=o&101=y&102=e&103=r&104=N&105=o&106=%22&107=%3A&108=1&109=8&110=4&111=%2C&112=%22&113=i&114=d&115=%22&116=%3A&117=1&118=8&119=4&120=%2C&121=%22&122=t&123=e&124=x&125=t&126=%22&127=%3A&128=%22&129=0&130=0&131=2&132=1&133=3&134=4&135=+&136=%7C&137=+&138=n&139=u&140=l&141=l&142=%22&143=%7D&144=%5D
```

If I do JSON.stringify(employerKey) I get The Params HERE Are  undefined=&undefined= in the console log. The undefined matches how many selections I have made in the input.

Here is where I'm making my ajax call and passing the data

```
$jw.secureAjax({
                url : "usersMemberAdd.action",
                success : function(data, status, xmlreq) {
                    DataTableUtils.addRow($("#employerClientTable").DataTable(), data);
                    var tr = $("#employerClientTable > tbody > tr:last");
                    tr.attr("id", "");

                },
                data : "employerNo=" + employerKey.id + "&userNo=" + $("#usersNo").val()
            });
        });
```

As you can see, I was able to access the object and its property before I used Select2 multi selection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have searched around for awhile now for a solution. Thank you!

Comment: employerKey isn't defined?

Comment: Hi Kobe, the array DOES have data as follows - 

```0: {…}
​​
employerNo: 187
​​
id: 187
​​
text: "002137 | null"
​​
webserviceId: "eci"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: {…}
​​
employerNo: 186
​​
id: 186
​​
text: "002136 | null"
​​
webserviceId: "eci"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with that is working for me. I wasn't sure if there was a better way to handle this from the select2. Thank you.

```
    var employerKeyArray = $("#employerSearch_id").select2("data");
        var parameterString = "";

        for(var i=0 ; i < employerKeyArray.length ; i++){

            var selectedOption = employerKeyArray[i];

            if(i > 0){

                parameterString += "&";
            }

            parameterString += "multiEmployerKeys=" + selectedOption.id;


        }
```